# Buy credits for prepaid mobile in another country

Tags: cellphones, mobile-operators

I have an Orange prepaid SIM card from Poland.

I'm going to Berlin next Monday and I think that I'll have to use my credits from my SIM card to use Internet (or Orange roaming is free?)

(here in Poland I can use free until my limit of 2Gb)

So my question is: can I buy more Orange credits in Berlin and simply type that code `<lot of numbers>`?

Comment: I have never seen a shop in Germany that sells foreign prepaid recharge cards. Maybe it is possible to buy credits online but best is to charge before you leave.

Comment: Hum, now I'm scared since I have no idea about the prices for roaming.

Answer (score 4):

You can probably buy credit online for your Polish SIM card while in Berlin (I have held several pay-as-you-go SIM cards in various countries and it was always possible).

But you should not assume that credit/plans from the same brand are somehow related between countries. Conditions are sometimes very different and shop-bought credit is typically only valid with a SIM card from that country.

If credit for a Polish SIM card is available at all (I doubt it is), it will be a separate product. Technically and commercially, mobile phone networks in different countries are independent from each other, even when they share an international brand like Orange, Vodafone or T-Mobile. Some of them do offer free roaming/integrated offers across several countries (I think it's the case in the Middle East in particular) but it's not a given.

Beyond that, roaming prices – whether on a partner network or not – within the EU are regulated, but still not very cheap for data (see previous questions on this site for more).

Comment: Dear Relaxed, thanks a lot. I read about the roaming prices. I guess that 0,20 Euro/Mb. Since I have no idea what I can do with 1Mb, maybe I'll ask for roaming plans.

Comment: I use a Dutch prepaid phone and can no longer buy by credit card. Now if I need to buy credit while abroad I might have to contact someone at home to buy credit and send the code to me.

Comment: @Sigur Recently in the Middle East we got these cool roaming plans, for small amount we can get a daily/weekly/monthly plans (1gb/5gb/unlimited respectively). You might also have something like that. If not, then your best option is to buy a local sim card.

Comment: @Willeke, your info is very useful. Since I don't have anybody to buy to me I'll think in buy before. Thanks.

Comment: @Willeke Maybe yours is different but I always could buy with ideal. Not CC but perfectly doable from abroad. You do need a Dutch bank account, though.

Comment: Relaxed: KPN Prepaid does not offer that option, so I buy before I leave the country, but in case of emergency I can/have to ask someone at home to buy.